# How to get file uri from entity video

Tags: media, 9

I have some code to get video using view builder.

```
$view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('media');
$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('media');
$entity_id = $storage->load($course_video_source[0]['target_id']);
$build_video_course = $view_builder->view($entity_id, 'default');
$video_html = render($build_video_course);
```

The `$video_html` is returned html string as an object.
How do I get the source file only without the `<video>` tag?

```
object(Drupal\Core\Render\Markup)#21215 (1) {
  ["string":protected]=>
  string(426) "<div><div><div class="visually-hidden">Video file</div><div><div class="video--wrapper"><video-js class="video-js video-container" playsinline="true" crossorigin="anonymous"><source  src="/milo/docroot/sites/default/files/2021-05/1.%20LARI%20-%20SEJARAH%20%28UPDATE%20TERBARU%2016%20Mei%29%20-%203.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video-js></div></div></div></div>"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with a Media entity:

```
$media_type = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('media_type')->load($media->bundle());

$file_field_name = $media_type->getSource()->getSourceFieldDefinition($media_type)->getName();

$file_uri = $media->get($file_field_name)->entity->getFileUri();
```